Error when raising Samba 4.19 Functional Level
I raised the functional level of my Samba 4.19 server with the commands below, the Schema update took a long time but ended successfully, however when raising the functional level with the second command the error below occurred and I was unable to complete the complete process. Can anyone tell me what could have happened or if they have experienced this?

samba-tool domain schemaupgrade --schema=2019
samba-tool domain functionalprep --function-level=2016
samba-tool domain level raise --domain-level=2016 --forest-level=2016

Error:
Exception: (1, 'descriptor_modify on CN=XXXX,CN=XXXX,DC=XX,DC=XXXX,DC=XX failed: (-30788) - MDB_TXN_FULL: Transaction has too many dirty pages - transaction too big at ../ ../lib/ldb/ldb_mdb/ldb_mdb.c:203')
cancel called but no ldb transactions are active!
ERROR(ldb): uncaught exception - descriptor_modify on CN=XXXX,CN=XXXX,DC=XX,DC=XXXX,DC=XX failed: (-30788) - MDB_TXN_FULL: Transaction has too many dirty pages - transaction too big at . ./../lib/ldb/ldb_mdb/ldb_mdb.c:203
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sernet/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 279, in _run
return self. run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sernet/samba/netcmd/domain/functional_prep.py", line 137, in run
samdb.transaction_cancel()

*O DC And CN I put X just to not expose the company I work for.
Thanks
